# How to read fixed32 integer using protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, c++, serialization, protocol-buffers

This seems like a basic question but i have doubts maybe because i am using 2 different libraries to write and read the data. My Write program is written in c++ which uses google's protocol buffer library. My reader is implemented in .NET c#.

In write program, i write a file header as follows.

```
coded_output->WriteLittleEndian32(BIN_START_MAGIC_NUMBER);
coded_output->WriteLittleEndian32(major_version);
coded_output->WriteLittleEndian32(minor_version);
coded_output->WriteVarint32(strlen(_region));
coded_output->WriteRaw(_region, strlen(_region));
coded_output->WriteLittleEndian32(_offset);
```

What is the corresponding function in C# to read the above fields? I understand how to read the protocol buffer messages but not sure about how to read above data.

Regards,
Alok

Comment: Assigning file u wrote these too to file stream, than use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx
There u can specify what to read, for example WriteLittleEndian32 is 32 bits

Comment: @nikolaMM94 while reading 4 bytes is pretty simple (although *even that* is actually not as simple as just calling Read passing count = 4), strings are noticeably trickier, since you would also need to process varint encoding.

Comment: I support I will be able to read Little endian 32 bit integers. What about Varint32 integers. I guess this will be in a coded and wont be able to read by FileStream directly. Is there any corresponding read function in C# ?

Comment: @Marc, precisely my question regarding string. Would you suggest where can i find documentation on this?

Comment: @Marc, checking your reply now.

Comment: @Alok in that case, the **pair** of WriteVarint32 and WriteRaw should map to the second example (Base128, then UTF8)

Comment: ah, for some reason I got it into my head that `_region` was a string - is that the actual payload? if so, there is a much better way of processing that (i.e. as a length-capped message). I can add an example if this is the case.

Comment: btw; I added some static utility methods onto ProtoReader for scenarios like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file header is **not** a valid protobuf sequence, and consequently the standard reading mechanisms in protobuf-net won't be geared to reading it - indeed, a `ProtoReader` would not let itself get into a state to read that, since it is invalid. However! To read a little-endian 32-bit number, you can probably use:

```
int x, int y; // ignore
int value = ProtoReader.ReadLengthPrefix(stream, false, PrefixStyle.Fixed32,
                      out x, out y);
```

Assuming that the coded stream is using standard protobuf conventions, the string is written as a varint length-prefix and then UTF-8, so you could use:

```
int x, int y; // ignore
int length = ProtoReader.ReadLengthPrefix(stream, false, PrefixStyle.Base128,
                      out x, out y);
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
int read, offset = 0;
while(length > 0 && (read = stream.Read(bytes, offset, length)) > 0) {
    offset += read;
    length = read;
}
if(length > 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

I can probably package those more conveniently for you if you really want; they aren't exposed currently because *that isn't protobuf* ;p

Comment: does WriteVarint32() specifies how big will string be?

Comment: @nikolaMM94 The WriteVarint32 maps to the ReadLengthPrefix with Base128 (I really must rename that to varint...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked out well. I can work with the provided solution.

Comment: I understand that this is not a valid protobuf sequence, but i think many developers will use this code, so probably easier to package it as a function. To read a string with given length prefix ?

Comment: @Alok is as shown in my second example above. If you mean "can you add methods to do that more conveniently"... probably, yes ;p

Comment: @Alok they are there in r478? whatever the current on google-code is, anyway